# Importing Apache HTTP Components Android Studio 1.3.2

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use Apache HTTP components to provide my android application with live currency rates. I have the following code to import these but have errors

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.ParseException;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

I have tried the following JAR http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhttpclient403jar.htm with no luck. Is there any other way of implementing this?

Comment: [Connecting to the Network](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html) is worth a read for how to use `HttpURLConnection`

Answer (score 1):

The Apache HTTP client is now deprecated. You'll want to use [`HttpURLConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) instead to make web calls.

See the release notes for more info here: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client

> To continue using the Apache HTTP APIs, you must first declare the
>   following compile-time dependency in your build.gradle file:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a fairly up-to-date independent packaging of Apache HttpClient via the `cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.4.1.1` artifact. So, in Android Studio, for the module where you want to use HttpClient, you would have:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.4.1.1'
}
```

Note that the API for current editions of HttpClient, such as what you get from the above library, is different than the API for the deprecated-and-gone edition of HttpClient that was baked into Android and used to be part of the Android SDK.

Personally, I would recommend that you use [OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp) instead.